# Why the graphd congif file doesn't register to the meta server in Nebula Graph?

Tags: nebula-graph

I'm compiling the source code to use Nebula Graph and using the `nebula.service` script to start the services.When I start nebula services for the first time, I can't create spaces But I found graphd Config File Doesn't Register to Meta Server and the services don't run well.

Answer (score 0):

When starting Nebula Graph services with the nebula.service script, graphd, metad and storaged processes start too fast to make the graphd config file registered into the meta server. The same problem may also occur when restarting.

If you are using the beta version, start the metad service first, then the storaged and graphd to avoid such problem.